# Podio - How do I create a contact when "Create Space Contact" is deprecated?

Tags: podio

I want to create a contact using the Podio API, but I can see that Contact > Create Space Contact is deprecated and will be removed soon. How should I create a contact?

[Podio documentation: Contact](https://developers.podio.com/doc/contacts/create-space-contact-65590)

Answer (score 1):

Podio Workspace Contacts are deprecated, you should use "Contacts" app instead. Then all operations with contacts are `item` operations because each contact is usual Podio item.

Here are some more details about it: https://help.podio.com/hc/en-us/articles/201019938-Using-a-Contacts-app-Importing-Contacts